# Do bootstrap takes "col-xs" automatically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap class is `class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"`. I have not used `col-xs`.

Will Bootstrap automatically take `col-xs` as `col-xs-12` when the screen is reduced to extra small screen size?

Comment: No. It only works on the classes which you apply

Comment: I would say everything is explained here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid. Simply thing differenty, see when the classes you added are applied and when they are not (the *when they are not* means the default behavior)

Comment: Not really. With no classes being applied at the xs size the elements, if they're block level like a div, would appear to act as if they had col-xs-12 applied, but they're just default to their normal behavior.